# Is there such a thing as a Strange Iron Curtain?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-heavy

I love the *Iron Curtain* reskinned stock minigun (awarded via "Poker Night at the Inventory"), and have put a Professional Killstreak kit on it. I'd really like to strangify it too, though, and there don't seem to be any Iron Curtain Strangifiers on the community market. None of my research has shown up any such thing... but nothing has proven it impossible either.

Do strangifiers exist for all weapons? Or alternatively, is there such a thing as a "generic strangifier", able to be applied to any weapon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this table](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_quality/Possible_weapon_qualities), the Iron Curtain does not have a Strange quality. Strangifiers only exist for weapons that are able to have the Strange quality.

Comment: Awwwwww, oh well. Maybe they'll make a strangifier in a future patch?

Comment: Not impossible, but highly unlikely. It's a promo item that is several years old now, and there are very, _very_ few promo items in the game that can be obtained in strange quality.

Comment: Sad. Oh well. If ever there's a generic strangifier, I'll be massively interested.